# Starting with TYPO3 8.6

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I'm quite beginner with TYPO3 and I have to migrate web from TYPO3 4.7 to TYPO3 8.6. I started with reading manuals and trying to create for example "provider extension" but it doesn't work. I also read that there are many changes in version 8.x so I can't follow fluid manuals which are for older versions.
Can you please give me an advice how to start? or any step-by-step manual? 
Thank you

Comment: wait until typo3 8.7 LTS is out. Do not start with an unstable version.

Comment: at this moment I'm trying to get the feel of thing so that when LTS is out I don't have to study the basics. Or will it be that different?

Comment: There is 11 days time for coming TYPO 8 LTS, and may i know where are you getting issue? i would suggest you to start with templating method of your design integration and for sure the extension method EXT_BASE will work on TYPO3 8.x

Comment: :) I'm a beginner and what I really need is a step-by-step manual on how to make a simple fluid template work on typo3 8.x. So far I have tried this manual https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/introduction/extension-base.html  that got me confused and intimidated (also when I followed steps it doesn't work) .
So I guess what I'm trying to find is a way to get from clean typo3 install (with introduction package) to a fluid based template that would dysplay content and nothing else for now, so that I can understand the basics and work from there

Comment: There are several tutorials about the basics of templating with fluid.Take a look: http://typo3buddy.com/typo3-template-tutorial/fluid/ or https://wiki.typo3.org/T3Doc/Fluidtemplate_by_example or https://typo3worx.eu/2016/02/fluid-styled-content-next-generation-typo3-templating/

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept of TYPO3 remains the same, even between LTS versions. There are mostly small changes in the area of basic TYPO3 usage.

I recommend you to go through the basic tutorials using TYPO3 8.7 (the current LTS version), even they are not yet updated for it:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Tutorials.html

In case you also want to start to develop extensions, I recommend to read: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/Books/Index.html

Last but not least you mentioned you would like to upgrade from 4.7 to 8 LTS. This has to be done over the LTS versions, so you have to go from 4.7 to 6.2 to 7.6 to 8.7. For this I recommend you to read:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/Upgrade/Index.html

Please be aware that there were a lot of extension which worked in 4.7, but do not have a new version or a successor with a migration path.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've heard you can't upgrade from 1 version to another at once. First you have to upgrade to 5, then 6 then 7 then 8.

So download extentions for that version, run migration and database analyser each time. At the end you could still have some errors ( I usually do...  ) so you'll want to fix those manually or replace the broken extentions..

**Pro Tip:**

If you're working on Linux (which I would recommend) than you could download each Typo3 version into a folder and create a symlink to the Typo3 installation itself.

```
ln -s /var/www/symlinks/latest_76 typo3_src; ln -s typo3_src/index.php; ln -s typo3_src/typo3;
```

So in the symlinks folder I have the Typo3 installations (downloaded from their website) and renamed verison 7 to latest_76. You just run that command inside/var/www/websites/yourwebsite

Once 1 migration is done just delete the symlink and create a new one for the next version.